# How do I interpret all these parameters?

Tags: linear-model, interpretation

````
Call:
lm(formula = log(psoda) ~ prpblck + log(income) + prppov, data = wooldridge::discrim)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.32218 -0.04648  0.00651  0.04272  0.35622 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.46333    0.29371  -4.982  9.4e-07 ***
prpblck      0.07281    0.03068   2.373   0.0181 *  
log(income)  0.13696    0.02676   5.119  4.8e-07 ***
prppov       0.38036    0.13279   2.864   0.0044 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.08137 on 397 degrees of freedom
  (9 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.08696,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.08006 
F-statistic:  12.6 on 3 and 397 DF,  p-value: 6.917e-08
```
````

Comment: Can you please give us a little bit more context and show us what you've tried so far? CrossValidated is aiming to answer *specific* statistical questions for people who are stuck; it's not a place where we will do your statistics for you. What are you trying to find out? Can you say why you log-transformed the response and one of the predictors but not the other?

Comment: This looks like a common question in econometrics: does anything in This looks like a standard textbook question: a google search for "A model with a constant price elasticity with respect to income may be more appropriate" finds lots of hits ...